# What are the conventions for naming workflow activities in windows workflow foundation?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

What naming conventions to be followed when naming the activities?. For example what should be the name for a CodeActivity that sends email to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real convention. My general advise is to use meaningful names for people who look at the workflow diagram as that is all they have to see what an activity does.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for meaningful name as Maurcie mentioned but additionally I would ad the suffix Activity.

For your concrete case I would name the activity **SendMailActivity**.

Reasons:

1. The first part (SendMail) describes what it does and the suffix **Activity** shows where it can be used. (Workflow)
2. It becomes very handy in a large project when I have to search for an activity without knowing full name.

If you check the activities from .Net framework they have only a meaningful name (WriteLine,Assign)

It's just a personal preference. In the end is better to discuss with the rest of the team in order to agree for a convention.